# WSL issue: cannot execute C:\Windows\System32\Bash.exe from elevated PowerShell - “access is denied” - works in normal CMD/PS prompt (no admin rights)

Tags: ubuntu, powershell, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have an issue with WSL ([Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)) in PowerShell. If I run the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS app (the UWP app) it works as expected. However, if I run and run Bash.exe from an elevated PowerShell prompt, it fails with simply:

[image]

I opened C:\Windows\System32 then took ownership and granted Full-Rights to Bash.exe for myself. However, the issue persists. I have also tried:
- Uninstalling the Ubuntu UWP App, removing WSL via add/remove features
- Re-adding WSL via add/remove and reinstalling the Ubuntu UWP App: no change

**However, I have found that I can run Bash.exe in a normal (non-admin) CMD or PowerShell prompt. Why is this and how can I fix it?**

Comment: Iď try `Push-Location -Path $env:USERPROFILE` (or another non-system-protected path) before running `bash.exe`.

Comment: This issue has somehow just stopped. No idea what happened, perhaps the company changed a GPO or something.